# webgl 2d blending two transparent textures on top of each other

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl, blending

I am trying to blend two textures with an alpha channel over each other.

[image]

After looking through the net it appeared that there are no simple ways to solve this. I tried this trick in the fragment shader:

```
if(gl_FragColor.a < 0.5){
    discard;
}
```

This works for simpler textures with not a lot of alpha variations, like the human sprite in the background. But I want to be able to work with more complex images like the gradient sprite which doesn't work at all.

This is my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 fragColor;
varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
void main()
{
    vec4 tex = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
    gl_FragColor = tex * vec4(fragColor, 1.0);
    if(gl_FragColor.a < 0.5){
    discard;
}
}'
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 vertPosition;
attribute vec3 vertColor;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
varying vec3 fragColor;
varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;

uniform vec2 uvOffset;
uniform vec2 uvScale;

void main()
{
  fragColor = vertColor;
  gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(vertPosition.x, vertPosition.y, vertPosition.z, 1.0);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord * uvScale + uvOffset;
}
```

This is a part of the gl setup I use:

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ON);
```

Currently all sprites are being drawn on the same z axis, 0. However I don't know if the is the source of the problem as I tested giving each object a random z value and the problem persisted.

**Edit:**
In response to Rabbid76's comment.

This works verry well! <strike>The alpha is blended but the only problem is that the sprites look "burned":</strike>

[image]

I tried to alter the fragment shader to this:

```
<strike>gl_FragColor = tex * vec4(tex.rgb, tex.a);</strike>
```

But it still looks burned.

**Edit 2**

I solved it it. gl_FragColor should b:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.rgb, tex.a);
```

and not

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(fragColor* tex.rgb, tex.a);
```

otherwise it creates a burn blending effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently all sprites are being drawn on the same z axis, 0.

Since the dept test is enabled ([`gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/enable)), and the default depth function ([`depthFunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/depthFunc)) is `gl.LESS`, the second drawn sprite won't pass the depth test.
 You have to disable the depth test:

```
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

Further I recommend to adapt the blend function ([`blendFunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendFunc)):

```
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Or you use [Alpha premultiplication](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre). Therefore you have to adapt the fragment shader:

```
gl_FragColor = tex * vec4(fragColor * tex.rgb, tex.a);
```

And you have to use the following blend function ([`blendFunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendFunc)):

```
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Note, you don't need `if(gl_FragColor.a < 0.5) discard;` any more.